# How to make text in .col-xs-3 align to horizontal line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code:

```
<div class="container" style="width:300px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="media col-xs-3">qq</div>
    <div class="media col-xs-3">sohu</div>
    <div class="media col-xs-3">uc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the screenshot:

[image]

how to make qq, sohu, uc align to same horizontal line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the media class, this adds padding/margin to the first child.

More info on media:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
.media:first-child {
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

or you have to remove all media classes in div section.